# Sql Server - Join and group with table which has more records

Tags: sql-server, join

I have below 4 tables :

- User
- Student
- Department
- Marks

I am trying to fetch Total number of students and sum of total marks by DepartmentId. For ex my result set should say Department Id 1 has 50 students and 1200 total Marks scored by all students in all exams across department.

Below query gives me correct result when i need Total Marks by Department

```
SELECT DepartmentId, SUM([Value]) AS TotalMarks FROM [dbo].[Marks] M
WHERE CollegeId = 3
GROUP BY DepartmentId
```

Below query gives correct result when i need only Total number of Students by Department.

```
SELECT S.[DepartmentId], COUNT(U.[StudentId]) AS TotalStudents
FROM [dbo].User U
INNER JOIN dbo.[Student] S
ON U.[UserId] = S.[UserId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].Department D
ON D.[DepartmentId] = S.[DepartmentID]
WHERE D.[CollegeId] = 3 AND U.[IsFullTimeStudent] = 1
GROUP BY S.[DepartmentId]
```

Now when i want to get Total Number of Students and Total Marks by Department in a single result using below query i am facing issues. My Marks table can have multiple number of record for single user and for that reason it giving redundant result.

```
   SELECT S.[DepartmentId], COUNT(U.[StudentId]) AS TotalStudents, SUM(M.[Value]) AS TotalMarks
   FROM [dbo].User U
   INNER JOIN dbo.[Student] S
   ON U.[UserId] = S.[UserId]
   INNER JOIN [dbo].Department D
   ON D.[DepartmentId] = S.[DepartmentID]
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[Marks] M
   ON D.[DepartmentId] = M.[DeprtmentId]
   WHERE D.[CollegeId] = 3 AND U.[IsFullTimeStudent] = 1
   GROUP BY S.[DepartmentId]
```

My marks table has UserId, DepartmentId ,CollegeId, Value fields.

For Ex :- If there are  110 entries for DepartmentId 1 in marks table and 1 Student who is an FTE student then in this case TotalUsers i am getting 110 Total Students though that Department has only 1 student because there are 110 entries in Marks i am getting as 110 Total Students

Is there any simpler way to get this resolved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sample data and table definitions would be useful. I invented my own sample data, it should almost fit your table definitions.

Using `cross apply` or `outer apply` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql#using-apply) and [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql#k-using-apply)) allows to combine the count and sum results.

**Sample data**

```
create table departments
(
  departmentid int,
  departmentname nvarchar(20)
);
insert into departments (departmentid, departmentname) values
(1000, 'Business Faculty'),
(2000, 'Science Faculty' ),
(3000, 'Maintenance'     );

create table users
(
  departmentid int,
  userid int,
  username nvarchar(10),
  isfulltimestudent bit
);
insert into users (departmentid, userid, username, isfulltimestudent) values
(1000, 1, 'Alice',    1),
(1000, 2, 'Bob',      0),
(2000, 3, 'Clarence', 1),
(2000, 4, 'Britt',    0);

create table students
(
  userid int,
  studentid int
);
insert into students (userid, studentid) values
(1, 100),
(2, 200),
(3, 300);

create table marks
(
  departmentid int,
  userid int,
  mark int
);
insert into marks (departmentid, userid, mark) values
(1000, 1, 15),
(1000, 1,  8),
(1000, 2, 13),
(1000, 2, 12),
(2000, 3, 10),
(2000, 3,  7),
(2000, 3, 15),
(2000, 4, 10);
```

**Solution**

```
select d.departmentname,
       ts.TotalStudents,
       tm.TotalMarks
from departments d
outer apply ( select count(1) as TotalStudents
              from users u
              where u.departmentid = d.departmentid
                and u.isfulltimestudent = 1 ) ts
outer apply ( select sum(m.mark) as TotalMarks
              from marks m
              where m.departmentid = d.departmentid ) tm;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90ad5c363b081ee66bff4936612d0f15) to see it in action.

---

**Applied solution**

*Untested* query that merges the queries from your question:

```
SELECT d.DepartmentId,
       tm.TotalMarks,
       ts.TotalStudents
FROM dbo.Department d
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT SUM(m.[Value]) AS TotalMarks
              FROM dbo.Marks m
              WHERE m.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId ) tm
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT COUNT(u.StudentId) AS TotalStudents
              FROM dbo.User u
              JOIN dbo.Student s
                ON u.UserId = s.UserId
              WHERE u.IsFullTimeStudent = 1
                AND s.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId ) ts
WHERE d.CollegeId = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you Sander, its a great help.